# Не получается правильно позиционировать элемент после нажатия кнопки

Tags: html, css, position

У меня есть меню, которое по нажатию кнопки, выезжает вправо на 250px, сдвигая основной контент на такое же значение. Я не могу правильно обработать нажатие кнопки, чтобы при нажатии она тоже отъезжала на 250px вместе с sidebar-ом (она стоит на месте).

HTML-код кнопки:

```
<button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info toggleBtn">
    <span>☰</span>
</button>
```

CSS-код кнопки:

```
/* кнопка схлопывания */
#sidebarCollapse {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 60px;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добрый день! Есть ли пример для просмотра?

Comment: @DjangoStudent, я добавил 1 фотографию. Если этого не достаточно, я еще скину

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я такую задачу делаю с помощью Checkbox. Вот Мой код

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,400i,500');
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  left: -250px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #bdbddb;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.sidebar header {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #bdbdff;
  user-select: none;
}
.sidebar ul a{
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 65px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.1);
  transition: .4s;
}
ul li:hover a{
  padding-left: 50px;
}
.sidebar ul a i{
  margin-right: 16px;
}
#check{
  display: none;
}
label #btn,label #cancel{
  position: absolute;
  background: #bdbdbd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
label #btn{
  left: 40px;
  top: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  transition: all .5s;
}
label #cancel{
  z-index: 1111;
  left: -195px;
  top: 17px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 9px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
#check:checked ~ .sidebar{
  left: 0;
}
#check:checked ~ label #btn{
  left: 250px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
#check:checked ~ label #cancel{
  left: 195px;
}
#check:checked ~ section{
  margin-left: 250px;
}
section{
  background: url(bg.jpeg) no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <label for="check">
      <i class="fas fa-bars" id="btn"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-times" id="cancel"></i>
    </label>
    <div class="sidebar">
    <header>Сим-сим</header>
  <ul>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-qrcode"></i>Мужские )))</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-link"></i>Легкие</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-stream"></i>Средные</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-calendar-week"></i>Сложные</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><i class="far fa-question-circle"></i>Для Гениев</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<section></section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: иконка зачем то зависает. При перезагрузке она появится

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Я адаптировал под себя немного элементов. P.S. Там было написано Детские))

Comment: Не за что. Я рад, что помог